# How can i implement Fuzzy grouping in mongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, group-by, fuzzy-search

How can i implement Fuzzy grouping in mongoDB?

Example:

suppose i have a collection name 'TestCollection' that may contain duplicate records or may contain similar records so i want to group those records which are similar and duplicate?
I know about Fuzzy Logic(Fuzzy algorithm) that is about to find the partial truth.

in my case its about to similarity of two strings.so here is what i have done using Fuzzy algorithm:

```
string textToSearch= "2513, North Campus, Hudson Ln,Camp, USA";
string textToMatch= "A-284 bhalswa dairy, gurjar chowk nr yadav chowk bhalswa dairy, near Jhil, Bhalswa Dairy, USA";

var isTrue= DuoVia.FuzzyStrings.StringExtensions.FuzzyEquals(textToSearch, textToMatch, requiredProbabilityScore: 0.8);
```

in the above example 'isTrue' will be true if matching probability of these above string is  equal or more then 0.8, false otherwise.

but i want to find similar records in my mongodb collection using Fuzzy algorithm.

Is there any library to implement Fuzzy search algorithm  using C# in mongoDB or any other method?

**Original Data:**
[image]

**Expected Output: Similar records Grouped Based on Fuzzy string matching with 0.7 Probability:**

[image]

Comment: You can't use C# code in MongoDB. You can either do the grouping manually by retrieving records and running your own similarity code, or you could try to implement the fuzzy algorithm in javascript and use map/reduce. I doubt the algorithm can be implemented using aggregation, but you might check it out because it is the best option if it's available.

Comment: Can you please post a sample collection and the expected output?

Comment: `Elasticsearch` has this feature in built- http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-fuzzy-query.html. But if you want to do it on mongodb, you need to implement the logic of calculating the Levenshtein edit distance by yourself in javascript and then execute it on the server.